# A Proof question from a Chinese textbook

Tags: limits, analysis

Let $f$ be an increasing (decreasing) function defined on $[a, +\infty)$. Prove that a sufficient and necessary condition for the existence of $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ is that $f$ is in the upper (lower) bound of $[a, + \infty)$

Comment: What do you mean by "that $f$ is in the upper bound of $[a,+\infty)$"?

Comment: I couldn't make sense of it either, the question is written in Chinese this was what I got after running it through a translator App.

Comment: Intervals, such as $[a, + \infty)$, are sets. When it says that $f$ is in the upper (lower) bound of the interval, I think it is referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds . This diagram (from the same Wikipedia article) might help you visualize it: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Illustration_of_supremum.svg/2560px-Illustration_of_supremum.svg.png

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the actual version in chinese?

Comment: It probably means to say that $f$ has an upper bound on $[a,\infty)$ since this is the hypothesis of the monotone convergence theorem.